# How do I use the same ViewModel for two views?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So I have my `MainWindow.xaml` which has the DataContext of `BaseViewModel` set like this.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:BaseViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

it works fine, for instance when I select an item in my ListView it binds and updates my ImageView in my MainWindow.

```
<ListView Background="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ImageGridViewModel.Images}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ImageGridViewModel.SelectedImage}">
```

And then it updates like so

```
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageGridViewModel.SelectedImage}"
           Margin="20">
```

**Perfect no issues.**

However, I recently added a second view which is a `Window` called `WatermarkWindow` and I set the `DataContext` just like I did with the MainWindow, in the XAML like so.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:BaseViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And then the binding for the `Image` control on that new `Window`

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageGridViewModel.SelectedImage}"
       Margin="20">
```

However when I open that window, the `Image` control's source is not bound to the property, the property actually returns `NULL` and I think I know why that is, I think it's because in my `BaseViewModel` I am instantiating a `new` instance of that ViewModel evertime it gets called.

The reason to why I am doing it that way is because I wanted to instantiate a instance of it so I can actually use it to bind stuff. Rather than it being null.

If that's not the issue then I'm still really eager to learn and understand what the issue is.
What's the proper way of setting up a `BaseViewModel` that contains all the extra ViewModels?

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ImageGridViewModel ImageGridViewModel { get; set; } = new ImageGridViewModel();
}
```

And the ObservableObject

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And not that it matters because I know the properties work fine, here's the ViewModel.

```
    public class ImageGridViewModel
    {
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string SelectedImage { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: So you want the same view model **instance** for both views. Then you cannot create the view models in you XAML code but have to set the DataContext somewhere else.

Comment: Where do you reckon? I don't want to use Singleton.

Comment: From what I understood from your question, you are expecting that `ImageGridViewModel.SelectedImage` in the second window is the same as in the first. It does not need to be a singleton, just the same instance.

Comment: That's correct sir, and I was wondering how to get access to the same instance since I am instantiating a `new` instance everytime it gets called in the `BaseViewModel`

Comment: Is there any object having access to both window instances? Then you could do something like `window2.DataContext = window1.DataContext` there.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was setting the DataContext property to `this` where I instantiate the new `WawtermarkWindow`

```
if (wmw == null)
   {
       wmw = new WatermarkWindow();
       wmw.DataContext = this;
   }
```